Why Do I Need to Start a Slot Before Deploying a Serverless Linux Function App via Azure DevOps?
I'm trying to deploy a serverless Linux function app using Azure DevOps and I've run into an issue where the deployment fails unless I start the function app (or slot) first. This only seems to happen for Linux and not Windows function apps.
Here's my setup:

I'm using Azure Functions on a Linux Consumption App Service plan with no other apps
I have a separate deployment slot for our 'staging' environment.
The app is managed & provisioned via Terraform
I'm deploying through an Azure DevOps pipeline using the Azure CLI task to deploy.
If the slot is stopped (or the app is manually stopped), the deployment step fails. However, if I start the slot before running the deployment, everything works fine.

The error I get within my DevOps Pipeline is as follows:

##[error]Error: Failed to sync triggers for function app 'my-func-app'. Error: Unauthorized - Encountered an error (Forbidden) from extensions API. (CODE: 400)

I have a few questions:

Why do I need to start the deployment slot or function app before deploying to it?
Is there a way to deploy to a stopped slot on Linux function apps, or is this just a limitation of linux function apps? I couldn't see anything in the documentation for this

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you
I've tried both Windows and Linux, this doesn't seem to be a problem when deploying a windows function app.

If you run Azure CLI command in local PowerShell or CloudShell (without using pieplines) to deploy your package to the stopped slot of your Linux Azure Function app, will the issue be reproduced?

I was also getting the same error when I tried to Deploy the function app in slot when slot is in stopped state.

When I assigned Storage Account Contributor role to service connection service Principal in Storage associated with function and Contibutor to function app it worked for me.
Below Given .yml file which worked for me.

DevOps is my service connection name using service principal.

trigger:
- Dev

variables:
  # Function app name
  functionAppName: 'pyfunc31aug'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '.'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.11'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.11 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.6 as of today

    - bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'DevOps'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              deployToSlotOrASE: true
              slotName: staging

OUTPUT:



